# makefile gcc custom dynamic lib linking issue with .so file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

Guys I'm having a very hard time trying to make a custom .so file be correctly linked with the a another code file.

Where is the Makefile of the who creates the .so file:

```
#the compiler
CC = gcc

#the standart ompilation flags of the project
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

#path to the folder's root, where the holy not build framework is. Relate to this Makefile
PREPATH = ../

#Path to the SDL, SDL_image and Lua includes and libs
SDL2INCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)SDL2/include
SDL2LIBS = $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_test.a $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1 $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2main.a $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2.a $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2.so
SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)SDL2/SDL_image
SDLIMAGE2LIBS = $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_image.so $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0.0.0 $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_image.a
LUAINCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)lua/
LUALIB = -L $(PREPATH)lua/ -llua -lm

#Where to put the compiled program
COMPILEPATH = $(PREPATH)BINARIES/



#Build options

build: NLF.o
    cp ./*.o $(COMPILEPATH)
    $(CC) -shared $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDL2LIBS) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2LIBS) $(LUAINCLUDES) $(LUALIB) $(COMPILEPATH)*.o -o $(COMPILEPATH)libNLF.so

NLF.o: NLF_osservice.o NLF_Error.o NLF_event.o NLF.h.gch
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(LUAINCLUDES) -fPIC -c NLF.c

NLF.h.gch: NLF.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(LUAINCLUDES) NLF.h

NLF_osservice.o: NLF_osservice.h.gch
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(LUAINCLUDES) $(NLFINCLUDES) -fPIC -c NLF_osservice.c
NLF_osservice.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(LUAINCLUDES) $(NLFINCLUDES) NLF_osservice.h

NLF_Error.o: NLF_error.h.gch
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(LUAINCLUDES) $(NLFINCLUDES) -fPIC -c NLF_error.c
NLF_error.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(LUAINCLUDES) $(NLFINCLUDES) NLF_error.h

NLF_event.o: NLF_event.h.gch
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(LUAINCLUDES) $(NLFINCLUDES) -fPIC -c NLF_event.c
NLF_event.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) $(LUAINCLUDES) $(NLFINCLUDES) NLF_event.h  



#cleaning options

clean-build:
    rm -f -v $(COMPILEPATH)*.o

clean-hard clean-all:
    rm -f -v ./*.o ./*.h.gch
    rm -f -v $(COMPILEPATH)*.o $(COMPILEPATH)*.so

clean-soft clean-all-but-so:
    rm -f -v ./*.o ./*.h.gch
```

it's a bit long, but it's not hard ^^"
This one compiles normally and create the "libNLF.so" file in the "BINARIES" folder.
To be sure a run the command "nm -g libNLF.so | grep NLF", and it gives me between other things, this line:

> 0000000000001100 T NLF_init

Now lets to the problematic Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3
PREPATH = ../

SDL2INCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)SDL2/include
SDL2LIBS = -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_test.a -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1 -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2main.a -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2.a -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2.so
SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)SDL2/SDL_image
SDLIMAGE2LIBS = -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_image.so -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0.0.0 -L $(PREPATH)SDL2/lib/libSDL2_image.a
#LUAINCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)lua/
#LUALIB = -L $(PREPATH)lua/ -llua -lm

NLFINCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)NLF_SCR/
NLFLIB = -L ../BINARIES/libNLF.so


build:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) auto_genareted_code.c $(NLFINCLUDES) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(NLFLIB) $(SDL2LIBS) -o auto_genareted_code
```

and the GCC gives me:

> auto_genareted_code.c:(.text.startup+0x7): undefined reference to `NLF_init'
>   and all other funtions from libNLF.so are in the same situation.

does some one knows what the hack in going on?

Comment: The `-L` option to `gcc` adds an entry to the library search path.  This is a search path for *libraries*, not for *functions*, so it does not make sense to name individual library files that way.  It certainly does not cause them to be linked.  If you intend to give full paths to all the libraries then just give the library file names, without the `-L`.

Comment: On the other hand, the conventional way of specifying libraries would follow a pattern similar to this: `NLFLIB = -L../BINARIES -lNLF`.  The `-L` specifies an extra directory to search, and the `-l` names a specific library to link, less the initial "lib" and the extension.

Comment: to be very honest with you, i still do not fully understand why it do not work. But I did what you said and it worked!! =D thanks so much, a spend the last 2 days in it kkkkkk ^^"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to John Bollinger's solution, remember to put libraries linking at the end of compiler command, as order is important for library linking.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option;
>       the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the
>       order they are specified.
>       Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o' searches library`z' after file foo.o but
>       before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in `z', those functions
>       may not be loaded.